# Find walking distance from one GeoPoint to many Geopoints at a single time in Android Native Application?

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

I am working on a LBS application. And I need to find a walking distance from User Location to many other locations at a time. 
Suppose if Users Geopoint is G-A and the other destinations points are D1, D2 and D3, how can I find the walking distance between the G-A to D1, D2 and D3 at a same time and show them in MapView?
Do the google provides some fascilities for those kind of work?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results);
```

example

```
 public static double CalculateDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
 float[] result=new float[1];
 Location.distanceBetween (lat1,lng1,lat2, lng2,  result);
 return (double)result[0];
}
```

You can use this method in loop to calculate the distances from G-A to D1, D2, D3 and store them in array results.Just pass the lat and lng.